# Angular 8 httpclient how to send JSON header

Tags: asp.net, json, angular, httpclient, angular8

Im trying to send a JSON using the angular 8 HttpClient to an ASP.net core backend using the following code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '@/_models';

    login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`https://${config.apiUrl}/api/User/LoginUser`,
                JSON.stringify({
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password 
                })
        ).pipe(map(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log(user);
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
    }
}
```

However, when trying to send the JSON when logging in to the login page which is hosted using the command npm start, so

```
localhost:8080/login
```

is sending the request.

The request headers are:

```
POST /api/User/LoginUser HTTP/1.1
Host: (Checked_and_correct_API_URL)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:8080/login
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 49
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

the response headers are:

```
HTTP/2.0 415 Unsupported Media Type
content-type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 13:10:01 GMT
content-length: 147
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

and the sent parameters are:

```
{"username":"jeboimarc2","password":"KUTminor1!"}
```

Which is also correct

Can anyone tell me why i am getting the unsupported media type error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass raw json data, don't convert it to string.

Try like this:

```
return this.http.post<any>(`https://${config.apiUrl}/api/User/LoginUser`,{"username": username, "password": password })
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick answer, sorry i couldn't get back to this with all the holidays stuff happening. Now im getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) when sending the JSON. However i think this is due to the web-browser im running, i'll try a different one this afternoon